# Datapatch -verbose fails with erros

Tags: oracle-12c, patching

After succsessfuly doing the opatch apply for Oracle Patch Apr 2017, datapatch Fails with the following error:

```
D:\oracle\cfgtoollogs\sqlpatch\sqlpatch_4540_2017_07_07_22_18_44
MOS Note 1609718.1

D:\oracle\cfgtoollogs\sqlpatch\25872779\21307635



Adding patches to installation queue and performing prereq checks...
Installation queue:
  Nothing to roll back
  The following patches will be applied:
    25872779 (WINDOWS DB BUNDLE PATCH 12.1.0.2.170531(64bit):25872779)

Installing patches...
Patch installation complete.  Total patches installed: 1

Validating logfiles...
Patch 25872779 apply: WITH ERRORS
  logfile: D:\oracle\cfgtoollogs\sqlpatch\25872779\21307635/25872779_apply_AUSB2
_2017Jul08_06_56_39.log (errors)
    Error at line 76972: ORA-06550: Zeile 2, Spalte 3:
    Error at line 76973: PLS-00201: Bezeichner 'CTX_DDL.CREATE_PREFERENCE' muss
deklariert werden
    Error at line 76974: ORA-06550: Zeile 2, Spalte 3:
    Error at line 76976: ORA-06550: Zeile 3, Spalte 3:
    Error at line 76977: PLS-00201: Bezeichner 'CTX_DDL.SET_ATTRIBUTE' muss dekl
ariert werden
    Error at line 76978: ORA-06550: Zeile 3, Spalte 3:
    Error at line 76994: ORA-06550: Zeile 2, Spalte 3:
    Error at line 76995: PLS-00201: Bezeichner 'CTX_DDL.CREATE_PREFERENCE' muss
deklariert werden
    Error at line 76996: ORA-06550: Zeile 2, Spalte 3:
    Error at line 76998: ORA-06550: Zeile 3, Spalte 3:
    Error at line 76999: PLS-00201: Bezeichner 'CTX_DDL.SET_ATTRIBUTE' muss dekl
ariert werden
    Error at line 77000: ORA-06550: Zeile 3, Spalte 3:
    Error at line 77016: ORA-06550: Zeile 2, Spalte 3:
    Error at line 77017: PLS-00201: Bezeichner 'CTX_DDL.CREATE_PREFERENCE' muss
deklariert werden
    Error at line 77018: ORA-06550: Zeile 2, Spalte 3:
    Error at line 77020: ORA-06550: Zeile 3, Spalte 3:
    Error at line 77021: PLS-00201: Bezeichner 'CTX_DDL.SET_ATTRIBUTE' muss dekl
ariert werden
    Error at line 77022: ORA-06550: Zeile 3, Spalte 3:
    Error at line 77038: ORA-06550: Zeile 2, Spalte 3:
    Error at line 77039: PLS-00201: Bezeichner 'CTX_DDL.CREATE_PREFERENCE' muss
deklariert werden
    Error at line 77040: ORA-06550: Zeile 2, Spalte 3:
    Error at line 77042: ORA-06550: Zeile 3, Spalte 3:
    Error at line 77043: PLS-00201: Bezeichner 'CTX_DDL.SET_ATTRIBUTE' muss dekl
ariert werden
    Error at line 77044: ORA-06550: Zeile 3, Spalte 3:
    Error at line 77060: ORA-06550: Zeile 2, Spalte 3:
    Error at line 77061: PLS-00201: Bezeichner 'CTX_DDL.CREATE_PREFERENCE' muss
deklariert werden
    Error at line 77062: ORA-06550: Zeile 2, Spalte 3:
    Error at line 77064: ORA-06550: Zeile 3, Spalte 3:
    Error at line 77065: PLS-00201: Bezeichner 'CTX_DDL.SET_ATTRIBUTE' muss dekl
ariert werden
    Error at line 77066: ORA-06550: Zeile 3, Spalte 3:
    Error at line 77082: ORA-06550: Zeile 2, Spalte 3:
    Error at line 77083: PLS-00201: Bezeichner 'CTX_DDL.CREATE_PREFERENCE' muss
deklariert werden
    Error at line 77084: ORA-06550: Zeile 2, Spalte 3:
    Error at line 77086: ORA-06550: Zeile 3, Spalte 3:
    Error at line 77087: PLS-00201: Bezeichner 'CTX_DDL.SET_ATTRIBUTE' muss dekl
ariert werden
    Error at line 77088: ORA-06550: Zeile 3, Spalte 3:
    Error at line 77104: ORA-06550: Zeile 2, Spalte 3:
    Error at line 77105: PLS-00201: Bezeichner 'CTX_DDL.CREATE_PREFERENCE' muss
deklariert werden
    Error at line 77106: ORA-06550: Zeile 2, Spalte 3:
    Error at line 77108: ORA-06550: Zeile 3, Spalte 3:
    Error at line 77109: PLS-00201: Bezeichner 'CTX_DDL.SET_ATTRIBUTE' muss dekl
ariert werden
    Error at line 77110: ORA-06550: Zeile 3, Spalte 3:
    Error at line 77126: ORA-06550: Zeile 2, Spalte 3:
    Error at line 77127: PLS-00201: Bezeichner 'CTX_DDL.CREATE_PREFERENCE' muss
deklariert werden


Please refer to MOS Note 1609718.1 and/or the invocation log
D:\oracle\cfgtoollogs\sqlpatch\sqlpatch_9136_2017_07_08_06_56_02\sqlpatch_invoca
tion.log
for information on how to resolve the above errors.

SQL Patching tool complete on Sat Jul  8 06:57:07 2017
```

MOS Note 1609718.1 doesn't tell you how to fix this but I was able to roll it back (`datapatch -rollback  25872779 -force -verbose`)

Answer (score 1):

I had to install Oracle Text to fix this. DBCA -> Configure -> Install Oracle Text -> Create CTXSYS User